# Python gRPC cancel unary-stream call from client side

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

Using Python gRPC, I would like to be able to cancel a long-running unary-stream call from the client side, when a `threading.Event` is set.

```
def application(stub: StreamsStub, event: threading.Event):
    stream = stub.Application(ApplicationStreamRequest())
    try:
        for resp in stream:
            print(resp)
    except grpc.RpcError as e:
        print(e)
```

For the time being I am cancelling the stream using the `channel.close()` method, but of course this closes all connections rather than just this stream.

Could someone suggest how I can use the event to cancel the stream iterator? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Below is some code for a gRPC UnaryStream call. The server sends an unending number of replies, leaving the client to decide when to stop receiving them.

Instead of using a counter, you can have a thread go off and do some work, and set an event that is checked before calling cancel() instead of checking the counter.

Note: using Python 2.7

Protofile:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package my_package;

service HeartBeat {
    rpc Beats(Counter) returns (stream Counter) {}
}

message Counter {
    int32 counter = 1;
}
```

Client:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import grpc
import heartbeat_pb2
import heartbeat_pb2_grpc


def get_beats(stub, channel):
    try:
        result_iterator = stub.Beats(heartbeat_pb2.Counter(counter=i))
        for result in result_iterator:
            print("Count: {}".format(result.counter))
            if result.counter >= 3: # We only wants 3 'beats'
                result_iterator.cancel()
    except grpc.RpcError as rpc_error:
        if rpc_error.code() == grpc.StatusCode.CANCELLED:
            pass # Otherwise, a traceback is printed


def run():
    with grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:9999') as channel:
        stub = heartbeat_pb2_grpc.HeartBeatStub(channel)
        get_beats(stub, channel)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Server:

```
from concurrent import futures

import grpc
from proto_generated import heartbeat_pb2
from proto_generated import heartbeat_pb2_grpc
import time


class HeartBeatServicer(heartbeat_pb2_grpc.HeartBeatServicer):
    pass


    def Beats(self, request, context):
        # Not required, only to show sending the server a message
        print("Beats: {}".format(request.counter))

        def response_message():
            i = 0
            while context.is_active():
                print("Sending {}".format(i))
                response = heartbeat_pb2.Counter(counter=i)
                i += 1
                time.sleep(1)  # Simulate doing work
                yield response

        return response_message()


def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    heartbeat_pb2_grpc.add_HeartBeatServicer_to_server(
        HeartBeatServicer(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:9999')
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve()
```

Comment: Special thanks to Nordine Lotfi (user 12349101) and to MisterMiyagi (user 5349916) for their help in the SO Python chat for their help.

Answer (score 1):

The `_Rendezvous` object returned by a rpc call implements `grpc.RpcError`, `grpc.Future`, and `grpc.Call`, therefore cancelling the stream is as simple as calling `stream.cancel` (from `grpc.Future` interface)